# How to Fetch Data from OpenAQ API with Python: Filter by Country, City, and Specific Parameters?

Tags: python, fetch-api

I am working on a project where I need to forecast PM2.5 concentrations in mining areas. To achieve this, I require air quality data with specific parameters from cities with gold mining activities and their environs. I have compiled a list of cities that maybe helpful, however this is not exhaustive.

Parameters:
**PM2.5
PM10
Temperature
Wind Speed
Humidity
Pressure**

Cities:
Australia:
Kalgoorlie, Western Australia
Bendigo, Victoria

Canada:
Timmins, Ontario
Yellowknife, Northwest Territories

South Africa:
Johannesburg, Gauteng

United States:
Juneau, Alaska
Cripple Creek, Colorado
Sacramento, California

From **2018 to 2022**.

I am seeking assistance in writing a Python script to fetch this air quality data from the OpenAQ API. I intend to use this data for my forecasting model to analyze PM2.5 concentrations in relation to the given parameters in mining areas.

Any help in crafting the Python script and conducting data retrieval would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_openaq_data(api_key, city, country, parameter, start_date, end_date):
    url = f"https://api.openaq.org/v1/measurements?city={city}&country={country}&parameter={parameter}&date_from={start_date}&date_to={end_date}&limit=10000&order_by=datetime&sort=asc&api_key={api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data['results']
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    OPENAQ_API_KEY = "MY_KEY"

    cities_data = {
        "Ontario": {"city": "Timmins", "country": "Canada"},
        "Northwest Territories": {"city": "Yellowknife", "country": "Canada"}
    }

    start_date = "2016-01-01"
    end_date = "2019-12-31"

    parameters = ["pm25", "pm10", "wind", "humidity", "temperature"]

    for state, city_data in cities_data.items():
        city_name = city_data["city"]
        country_name = city_data["country"]

        print(f"Fetching data for {city_name}, {state}, {country_name}...")

        city_data = []
        for parameter in parameters:
            data = get_openaq_data(OPENAQ_API_KEY, city_name, country_name, parameter, start_date, end_date)
            city_data.append(data)

        # Combine data for all parameters into a single list
        combined_data = []
        for i in range(len(city_data[0])):
            record = {}
            for j in range(len(parameters)):
                record[parameters[j]] = city_data[j][i][parameters[j]]
            combined_data.append(record)

        # Save data to CSV file
        csv_filename = f"{city_name}_{state}_{country_name}_data.csv"
        with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=parameters)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(combined_data)

        print(f"Data for {city_name}, {state}, {country_name} saved to {csv_filename}.")
```